# como hacer efecto click

Tags: html, canvas, chart.js

Hola estoy utilizando chart.js y tengo este código

```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>
   <script src="utils.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <div id="canvas-holder">
   <canvas id="chart-area" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
   </div>
   <script>
   function colorFromValue(value, border) {
      var alpha = (1 + Math.log(value)) / 5;
  var color = 'purple';
  if (border) {
    alpha += 0.01;
  }
  return Color(color)
  .alpha(alpha)
  .rgbString();
}

Utils.load(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
  window.myTreeMap = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'treemap',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Basic treemap',
        data: [15, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2],
        backgroundColor: function(ctx) {
          return colorFromValue(ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex]);
        },
        spacing: 0.1,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'rgba(180,180,180, 0.15)'
      }]
    }
    }
  })
   });
  </script>
```

La cual da como resultado el treemap de cuadro por cuadro lo que quiero saber es como le puedo hacer para que al oprimir uno de los cuadros que salen en el treemap me mande un alert con los datos del cuadro que oprimió

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar algo así usando javascript

```
document.getElementById("chartId").onclick = function(evt){
    var clicked = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
}
```

Para más información, tienes disponible la documentación de chart.js con ejemplos y explicaciones: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html?h=getelementatevent